# How do I make a libGDX Desktop application resizable?

Tags: java, libgdx

libGDX Applications must implement the .resize(int width, int height) method, so I figured that resizing a libGDX app is not a big deal, but I found no way to make the actual application JFrame or whatever that is draggable as with JFrame.setResizable(true). Is that simply not possible with libGDX ?

Comment: Interesting. I don't have to do anything to make it resizable. My desktop application is always resizable. I think something is not right in your part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use gdx-backend-lwjgl for you desktop app, then you can use:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
config.resizable = true;
new LwjglApplication(new YourGame(), config);
```

Use newest source from SVN trunk.