# How to prohibit screen resize in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to have a constant value of screen size. How can I prohibit screen resizing? Should I do something with `viewport`?

```
public void resize(int width, int height){
    viewport.update(width,height);
}
```

Comment: On Android, iOS & GWT, you simply can't resize, because the size is fixed by the device/frame setup. On desktop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779108/how-do-i-make-a-libgdx-desktop-application-resizable - although it describes how to make it *resizable*, the exact boolean config flag `resizable` works two-way: simply set it to `false` - http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3443&p=16866 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define your screen size to constants and then use it like this:

```
public void resize(int width, int height){
  width = YOUR_DEFINED_WIDTH;
  height = YOUR_DEFINE_HEIGHT;
  viewport.update(width, height);
 }
```